# How to match trailing text in xpath?

Tags: xpath, xidel

```
<a href="xxxx"><i class="xxxx"></i>PDF</a>
```

Suppose that I have some HTML code like the above. I want to find `a` by matching the word `PDF`. `text()` does not work in this case. Could anybody show me what is the correct way to match trailing text like `PDF` in `a`? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the exact xpath expression you used?

Comment: Something like `//i[contains(text(), "PDF")]/parent:a` which does not work.

Comment: Try `//a[contains(./text(),"PDF")]` and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply use `//a[.='PDF']` as shown below.

[image]

Comment: What tool did you in the figure? Thanks.

Comment: Chrome dev tools, where you can see all the HTML under `Elements` tab.